# Sharepoint 2010 - create page with cropping image field

Tags: image, sharepoint-2010, crop

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 (as a beginner). I need to find the best way to allow a user to create a new page inside a sharepoint site. The page must have an image field which the user can crop when he creates the page.

I have 3 problems concerning this:

1. How can I allow my user to create the page in a single step. The default behaviour is: create page with Title, Url and Content type and the edit the page layout or the page properties. Is there a way to do this in a single step?
2. What view should my user use when editing the page? The "Edit page" view, or the "Edit properties"? I don't like the "Edit page" view because... it doesn't look like the right way to do it... BUT, I like the fact that I can use my custom BaseFieldControls in this view. The "Edit properties" look great, BUT, customizing it looks like a nightmare. And, of course, I cannot ask the user to use both views...
3. One of my requests is to allow the user to upload a sharepoint image for the page, and then to crop tree different sizes using the base image. The big question is: where should I allow my user to do this?

   1. In a webpart inside the "Edit properties" window? - Not very easy to integrate it. It seems almost impossible.
   2. In a custom BaseFieldControl in the "Edit page"? Would be great, but, I don't want the user to use this view.
   3. Create my own Asses Picker aspx page for the "Upload image" field, and replace the default one  - _layouts/AssetImagePicker.aspx? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer for everything but for number 1, maybe:

Check out SPServices. It is a Jquery project which is designed to help people use Jquery on Sharepoint sites. It is really useful for accessing, editing, and writing data is less lines of code than ever before... Unless you are a genius and have SP figured out which most do not.

To be honest, the only way to do things in "1 step" is with javascript anyway...

Hopefully you have heard of [Jquery](http://jquery.com/):